# Inner functions pulls call from outer function and causes error

Tags: r, scope

I'm using a function from the library leaps within another function. The last two rows of the leaps function in question goes:

```
rval$call <- sys.call(sys.parent())
rval
```

This apparently causes the call to the outer function to be passed to `rval$call`. And the actual call to the `regsubsets` function is needed as an argument later on.

Below an example to illustrate:

```
library(leaps)
#Create some sample data to perform a regression on
inda <- rnorm(100)
indb <- rnorm(100)
dep <- 2 + 0.1*inda + 0.2*indb + rnorm(100, sd = 0.3)
dfk <- data.frame(dep=dep, inda = inda, indb = indb)

#Create some arbitrary outer function
test <-  function(dependent, data){
  best.fit <- regsubsets(as.formula(paste0(dependent, " ~ .")), data = data, nvmax = 2)
  return(best.fit)
}
#Call outer function
best <- test("dep", dfk)
best$call #Returns "test("dep", dfk)"
```

So `best$call` will contain the call to the outer function (`test`), and not the call to the inner (`regsubsets`) function. As it's not really an option to change the inner function, is there any way of avoiding this problem?

EDIT:

One way around the problem could be something like this:

```
test <-  function(dependent, data){
  thecall <- 'regsubsets(as.formula(paste0(dependent, " ~ .")), data = data, nvmax = 2)'
  best.fit <- eval(parse(text = thecall))
  #best.fit$call <- [some transformation of thecall
  return(best.fit)
}
```

EDIT2:
    The reason I need to access what's inside $call is that it's needed in a predict function that I copied from Introduction to statitical learning:

```
predict.regsubsets <- function(regsubset_model, newdata, id, ...){
  form <- as.formula(regsubset_model$call[[2]])
  mat <- model.matrix(form, newdata)
  coefi <- coef(regsubset_model, id = id)
  xvars <- names(coefi)
  mat[, xvars] %*% coefi
}
```

In the second line it uses $call

Comment: What is the problem? As far as I can see everything works the way it’s supposed  to.

Comment: The problem is that best$call should contain regsubsets(as.formula(paste0(dependent, " ~ .")), data = data, nvmax = 2)

Comment: Not test("dep", dfk)

Comment: My point is: what makes you think that it should contain something else than what it contains? The code is very explicit about this, and (without having looked at the package’s code) this isn’t unreasonable.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong or unreasonable in some broader sense. I'm saying that $call will contain different tings depending on whether the regsubsets function is executed inside or outside a function. And my code won't work as a result of this.

Comment: Your code isn’t supposed to use the return value of `regsubsets` directly at all; the documentation is very clear: “`regsubsets` returns an object of class "regsubsets" containing no user-serviceable parts. It is designed to be processed by `summary.regsubsets`”. It would help if you could describe why your code needs the value, then we can suggest workarounds (in short, this question in its current form is an [x–y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968)).

Comment: The workaround I suggested would be a way around this if I could figure out how to turn the string I'm passing as eval(parse('regsubsets(as.formula(paste0(dependent, " ~ .")), data = data, nvmax = 2)') into an object of class call.

Comment: I'm adding some info above

Answer (score 1):

I’m still not entirely clear on how this is going to be used but in the case of your `test` function, you could write the following code:

```
test = function (dependent, data) {
    regsubsets_call = bquote(regsubsets(.(as.formula(paste0(dependent, " ~ ."))),
                                        data = .(substitute(data)), nvmax = 2))
    best_fit = eval(regsubsets_call)
    best_fit$call = regsubsets_call
    best_fit
}
```

However, the result may not work with downstream functions the package provides (though, realistically, it probably will; I’m guessing `summary.regsubsets` only uses it to print the call).

#### What’s going on here?

`bquote` constructs an unevaluated R expression; it’s similar to `quote` but it allows you to interpolate values (similar to `substitute`). `substitute(data)` means that, rather than putting the actual `data.frame` into the call (which would lead to a very unwieldy output, it puts the variable name (or expression) the user passed to `test`. So if the user called it as `test('mpg', mtcars)`, then the resulting expression would be

```
regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nvmax = 2)
```

The resulting call object is then (a) evaluated via `eval`, and (b) stored in the resulting `$call`.

Incidentally, the formula can (and, as far as I’m concerned, *should*) be constructed in the same way; no need to parse a string:

```
as.formula(bquote(.(as.name(dependent)) ~ .))
```

Taken together, the whole expression would then become:

```
formula = as.formula(bquote(.(as.name(dependent)) ~ .))
regsubsets_call = bquote(regsubsets(.(formula), data = .(substitute(data)), nvmax = 2))
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work. I'm using the thing to get cross validation errors in order to evaluate whether any lag order of a set of independents are useful for predicting either dependent variable in a set. So I've manually created a CV loop (from the book ISLR) and for that reason need to get the predicted values from the best function with n regressors.